# Receive Carrierwave URL through javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Is there a way to grab the Model.image_url through sql or javascript?

I have a select that when changed, I want the `<img src=>` to change dynamically.

With other situations I have done the following to change the background color of a div container:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :color_id, @other_model, :colors, :title, :id, :title, include_blank: "Select Color" %>

<div id="div" style="background-color:<%= "#{model.color.hex}" %>;">
...
</div>

**javascript**

var colors = <%= Color.pluck(:id, :hex).to_h.to_json.html_safe %>;
document.getElementById("model_color_id").addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementById("div" %>").style.backgroundColor = colors[this.value];
}, false);
```

For getting the carrierwave imgae, I tried a similar approach:

```
var product_mock = <%= Item.pluck(:id, :image).to_h.to_json.html_safe %>;
    document.getElementById("model_item_id").addEventListener("change", function(){
        document.getElementById("item").src = product_mock[this.value];
}, false);
```

but this isn't grabbing the `*.url'` or `*_url`

Tried a way like this for `onchange`:

```
$('#shop_product_item_id').on('change', function(){
    let item_id = $(this).val(); #tried with and without these 2 lines and with var
    console.log(item_id); #tried with and without these 2 lines
    var image = <%= Item.find(1).image_url %>;
    document.getElementById("id").src = image;
});
```

There is an id:1

nothing prints to console but the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.unique is not a function
```

Is there a way to grab this from carrierwave thorugh sql or even ruby within the javascript?

Comment: This type of ERB / Javascript may work for certain cases but the typical approach is to load data from the server using a REST endpoint. So you would fire a request using Javascript / jQuery (AJAX) and then do something with the result

Comment: So how can I get an entire record through javascript, then the Model.image_url in javascript? All of my attempts only return the actual database attributes in json or string but I cannot figure out how to get carrierwave in the mix.  I want to dynamically change an image based on the select chosen in a form without submitting the form.

Comment: I have been able to do it with storing the image directly in the app (assets>images) but I want to be able to fetch from carrierwave without storing the image

Comment: The url of the image cannot be obtained without actually storing the image on some storage.

Comment: @AlokSwain I meant without storing it in assets.  I want to be able to fetch from carrierwave url.  My only way to do what I want is by storing the images in my vendor folder but this isn't ideal.  I want everything to be dynamic and not need to be RESTful since I want everything on one page and not need to load a new one.  I cannot find a way to fetch the _url from carrierwave without loading a new page

Comment: really, a way to do this is to store the carrierwave url in a parameter itself --- which i likely will do if I cannot find a way soon

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code `Item.pluck(:id, :image).to_h.to_json.html_safe` to `Item.all.map{|item| [item.id, item.image_url]}.to_h.to_json.html_safe` . But as others said in comments better to get items through Ajax request not just store them in html.